# Error with thrust::device_vector in Cuda using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, makefile, cuda

I'm trying to compile and run the following simple cuda example in VS2012 with a makefile:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>

int main()
{
thrust::device_vector<double> my_new_vector(10); // create a vector of size 10
}
```

My makefile is very simple and just compiles it successfuly. When running the executable, it crashes! It seems it does not like `device_vector`. I'm running it with Windows 7/CUDA 8.0/VS2012. I have got the same error with CUDA 7.5. If I replace the line by a simple `std::cout << "hello world!\n";`it will run perfectly.

Is there any reason why `device_vector`does not work?

Comment: Any error message before the crash ? Can you also upload the makefile ?

Comment: probably because you are building a win32 executable.  Build an x64 executable.

Answer (score -1):

I just needed to change the `--gpu-name` option. Now it works!